# Python get output of child process

Tags: python, subprocess

The Perl file 1.pl:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

($b) = @ARGV;    
$a = 1;
$c = $a + $b;
print "$c\n";

exit;
```

The python file 1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess
b = 2
res = subprocess.call(["perl", "1.pl", str(b)])
print res
```

check out put

```
$python 1.py
```

output:

```
3
0
```

the output should 3,so what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0` is the [returncode attribute](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError.returncode).

```
$perl so.pl 2
3
$ echo $?
0            #this gets stored in `res`
```

Just use :

```
subprocess.call(["perl", "1.pl", str(b)])
```

If you don't want that `0` in the output.

You can also use [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to store the output of a command in a variable.

```
>>> res = subprocess.check_output(["perl", "so.pl", '2'])
>>> print res
3
```

Comment: subprocess.check_output is great!

Answer (score 2):

0 from the python. i. e you are storing the result in res variable and 3 is printing from the perl program

Answer (score 2):

In your perl script you use `print` to print something to screen, and `exit` to return a value. Calling `exit` without a number is equivalent to `exit 0`, which usually stands for success.

In your case your perl will print `3` and return `0`.

Later the python ignores the `3` and prints the `0`.

If you want to pass a number from your perl to your python either return that number using `exit $c` in perl or tell python to check the output of of your perl.